# The sum $1!+2!+3!+...+2007!$ is not a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, factorial

Today my teacher told me to prove this:-
Prove that $1!+2!+3!+...+2007!=\sum_{n=1}^{2007}(n!)  $ is neither a perfect square nor a perfect cube. Not getting any idea. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The tag ([tag:proof-theory]) is intended for questions about proof theory as a branch of mathematical logic, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-theory/info) and relevant [discussion on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11195/the-proof-theory-tag-is-misused-too-often). It is not intended for all questions related to proofs.

Answer (score 10):

All factorials starting with $5!$ are multiples of $10$ and thus have ones digit $0$. Since $1! + 2! + 3! + 4! = 33$, the number $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{2007} n!$ has ones digit $3$. Can it be a perfect square?

Answer (score 2):

$n!$ is a multiple of $7$ for $n\ge 7$. Hence the sum is $\equiv 1!+2!+3!+4!+5!+6!\equiv 5\pmod 7$.  Hence if your sum is a square $a^2$, then $a^6\equiv 5^3\equiv 6\pmod 7$, and if it is a cube $a^3$, then $a^6\equiv 5^2\equiv 4\pmod 7$. But $a^6\equiv 1\pmod 7$ by Fermat if $7\not\mid a$ , and $a^6\equiv 0\pmod 7$ if $7\mid a$. Therefore, the sum is neither a square nor a cube.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What is your sum modulo $7$?  What are the possible squares and cubes modulo $7$?