# Largest possible integer in series of factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find largest possible integer n such that $1!+2!+3!+... +n! =m^2$.

I can kind of guess the answer is 3, but I don't know how to get it. What's the first step in this question? Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773094/the-sum-123-2007-is-not-a-perfect-square

Comment: oh yes, i can't believe i didnt see that, thanks

Comment: Maybe look at the last digit of each side? So take mod 10 on both sides?